# Differentiate between minimize and rotate lifecycle events

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to differentiate the minimize event (ie. when the user hits the home button) to the rotate event. I am using lifecycle events (onPause, onStop, onDestroy) and onStop and onPause are called by both, while onDestroy only happens with a rotation. I would like to perform special functionality onStop (save some data) - is there a way I can tell from within that function whether it was a rotation event or minimize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [call `isChangingConfigurations()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29) in `onStop()` to determine if `onStop()` was called due to a configuration change.